# Как проверить на id формы Contact form 7 Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_posted_data', 'save_posted_data', $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1 );
function save_posted_data( $posted_data ) {
    if ($posted_data->id() == [290]) {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'reviews',
            'post_status'=>'draft',
            'post_title'=>$posted_data['your-name'],
            'post_content'=>$posted_data['your-message'],
        );
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($args);

        if(!is_wp_error($post_id)){
            if( isset($posted_data['your-name']) ){
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'your-name', $posted_data['your-name']);
            }
            // if( isset($posted_data['your-email']) ){
            //   update_post_meta($post_id, 'your-email', $posted_data['your-email']);
            // }
            // if( isset($posted_data['your-subject']) ){
            //   update_post_meta($post_id, 'your-subject', $posted_data['your-subject']);
            // }
            if( isset($posted_data['your-message']) ){
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'your-message', $posted_data['your-message']);
            }
            //and so on ...
            return $posted_data;
        }
    }
}
```

Сейчас при проверки так if ($posted_data->id() == [290]) { форма не отправляется.

Comment: А что выведет `var_dump( $posted_data->id() )` в самом начале функции?

Comment: Ничего, форма не отправляется, постоянно крутится http://prntscr.com/ml3p46

Comment: Ну в лог файл выведите. Надо узнать значение переменной.

Comment: В логе с ошибками пишет PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function id() on array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение, получить id формы Contact form 7 можно так

```
$form_id = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
if ($form_id->id == 290) {

}
```